# Derive partition sum for ideal gas (sum to integral)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, partition-function

Having the grand canonical partition sum:

$$\mathrm{Z} = \sum_{\{n\}}\exp{\left(-\beta \{\varepsilon_n(N_n) -\mu\,N_n\}\right)}$$

how to arrive at: $$\mathrm{Z} = \sum_{N = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{V^N}{h^{3N}N!}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\beta\,\left(\sum_{i = 1}^N\dfrac{p_i}{2\,\mathrm{m}}-\mu\,N\right)\right)\,\mathrm{\left(d^3p\right)}^N\quad ?$$

---

First things first,  from my lecture it follows: $\varepsilon_n(N_n) = \sum_{i}\varepsilon_i\,n_i$ as well as $N_n = \sum_i n_i$, thus:

$$\begin{align}\mathrm{Z} &= \sum_{\{n\}}\exp\left(-\beta\,\left(\sum_i\varepsilon_i\,n_i - \mu\sum_i n_i\right)\right)\\[12pt] & = \prod_i^N\sum_{n_i} \exp\left(-\beta\,(\varepsilon_i\,n_i-\mu\,n_i)\right)\end{align}
$$

From what I have found so far:

$$\sum_{n_i} \to\dfrac{1}{2^{3}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\,\mathrm{d^3n} \\[12pt] \text{[devision by 1/2 because the integral starts from neg. values, the sum not]}$$

as well as:  $$\mathrm{d^3n} = \dfrac{L^3}{(\pi\,\hbar)^3}\,\mathrm{d^3p} \\[12pt] [\text{this follows from QM: $p = \pi\,\hbar/L\cdot n$}] $$

For me this means:

$$\sum_{n_i} \to  \int\dfrac{L^3}{h^3}\,\mathrm{d^3p}$$

And so: $$\prod_i^{N}\sum_{n_i} \to  \int\left(\dfrac{V}{h^3}\,\mathrm{d^3p}\right)^N$$

In total I am arriving at:

$$ Z = \dfrac{1}{N!}\,\left(\dfrac{V}{h^3}\right)^N\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\beta\,(\varepsilon_i\,n_i-\mu\,n_i)\right)\,\left(\mathrm{d^3p}\right)^N \\[12pt] [\text{devision by 1/N! to devide by the arrangement of N identical particles}]$$

---

But, provided the steps are correct so far, how do I turn this into a summation over $N$?

As in the identity I need to show. I assume it can be written $\varepsilon_i = {p_i}^2/(2\,m)$